# Converting Action to LambdaExpression

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, action

I am using NRules and trying to load rules from database.

For that, I have to use reflection to generate an Expression.

```
public class Product
{
     public string Attribute1 { get; }
     public List<int> Category { get; set; }   
     public void AddCategory (int category){
          this.Category.Add(category);
     }
}
```

---

```
using NRules.RuleModel;
using NRules.RuleModel.Builders;

var builder = new RuleBuilder();
//some logic for buildin lefthand side
Expression<Action<IContext, Product>> action = (ctx, product) => product.AddCategory(25);
builder.RightHandSide().Action(action);
```

My goal is to generate "**`Expression<Action<IContext, Product>> action = (ctx, product) => product.AddCategory(25);`**" on runtime. I think the only way to do this to use reflection. Because I am reading some values from database.

I could generate the Action by using reflection:

```
Type actionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(IContext),      
Type.GetType(actualModelName) });
MethodInfo eventMethodInfo = type.GetMethod("AddCategory");
Action actionFromReflection  = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, eventMethodInfo);
```

But NRules method is expecting a LambdaExpression as a parameter.

How can I convert "actionFromReflection" to  LambdaExpression?

```
LambdaExpression le = actionFromReflection  ???
```

Comment: I would suggest you don't use reflection, but have a set of common commands that are driven by rules in the database, but aren't dynamically generated. I would guess your product designer thought 'hey database driven rules mean we can generate rules without any developer input' but in reality, that never happens.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the feedback. Actually it was our (developers) idea to generate the rules dynamically. Our rules are so simple.

Answer (score 2):

A delegate refers to real compiled Code, while a Lambda Expression is an Expression Tree, close to Source-Code, just not in Text-Form. You can Call your Delegate, but nothing else. Creating Source-Code from IL-Code would be a job for a Disassembler.

Using Reflection means "Use something already compiled", that is the opposite of creating it at runtime. So this is the wrong approach.

To create a LambdaExpression at runtime you do something like

```
        ParameterExpression ctx = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Context), "ctx");
        ParameterExpression product = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "product");

        LambdaExpression lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(
            /* your actual code, depending on what you want to do */
                Expression.Add(
                ctx,
                Expression.Constant(1)
            ),
            new List<ParameterExpression>() { ctx, product })
```

Actually this sample does build ctx => ctx +1
If you have no return value, you probably have an Expression.Call.
You have to further investigate, how to express what you want, as an expression Tree. That's a broad topic.

The LambdaExpression you can just cast:

```
var expr = (Expression<Action<ctx, product>>) lambdaExpr;
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading Holger's answer struggling couple of hours I've came up with this solution:

In order to create an expression like below on runtime:

```
Expression<Action<IContext, Model>> printExpression = (ctx, model) => model.AddCategory(5);
```

I've made a static method which generates an Action for my need:

```
public static Expression<Action<T, K>> GetActionExpression<T, K>(string methodName, int val)
{
    ParameterExpression ctx = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "ctx");
    ParameterExpression product = Expression.Parameter(typeof(K), "model");
    ParameterExpression actionMethodParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "val");

    var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, K>>(
        Expression.Call(
                  product,
                  typeof(K).GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { typeof(int) }),
                  Expression.Constant(val)), new ParameterExpression[] {
                  ctx, product
              }
        );
        return lambdaExpr;
}
```

This method generates an expression like this:

(ctx, model) => model.{methodName}(val);

Then I called this method by using reflection:

```
foreach(var item in actions) {

var actionMethodInfo = typeof(ExpressionBuilder).GetMethod("GetActionExpression")
                        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(IContext), type);

                    LambdaExpression action = (LambdaExpression)actionMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] {item.MethodName, item.Value });

}
```

And that's it.